# why do we need addRequestHeader method?

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest

Can anyone explain me the role of addRequestHeader method of ASIHTTPRequest class? Why do we need it?

P.S. Browsing over google and stackoverflow i see lots of people familiar with details of ASIHTTPrequest library. Where do you take the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any knowledge about that class, but most likely the method is used to send a custom header.

For example, when accessing a web service that is usually only hit through XHRs from JavaScript, it might require you to add a `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header.

Comment: do you think i may use any header and any value for this method?

Comment: Of course. The question is: Will the other side make use of this header? May proxies filter it out? If you use custom headers, I'd suggest you to name your header `X-whatever` to prevent possible collisions with standardized headers.

Answer (score 0):

The info is from [ASIHTTPRequest documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

You need the method to specify header of request.

[List of HTTP header fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Comment: should i always use this method?

Comment: No, depends on your request specification.

Comment: hmm... that is the problem. how do i know the specification? i should be pretty familiar with http before working with ASIHTTPRequest?

Comment: Did you at least tried to make an request? To see if it works or not, and if not what is the requestFailed, and what is the error?

Comment: no i didn't cause i have no server yet. it will be later. but i have to get the code ready for the moment when i just write actual server's name for the special constant named SERVER_URL and voulia - all requests work perfect. if i could test my code things would be much easier